Laravel Excel export iisues
i have php version 8.2.4 i want to install maatwebsite/excel version 3.1 but it is conflicting with requirement.enter image description here
composer require maatwebsite/excel:^3.1 --with-all-dependencies




The "3.1" constraint for "maatwebsite/excel" appears too strict and will likely not match what you want. See https://getcomposer.org/constraints
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update maatwebsite/excel --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel 3.1 -> satisfiable by
maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0].
- maatwebsite/excel 3.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
PS C:\Users\LE\CRUDAPP> composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires php ^7.0 but your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
used with all dependencies in myterminal command but no change.I was expecting it to install

sounds like you need to update the PHP requirement in your composer.json file to "^8.2.0"
